# What is the purpose of using Spring-orm?

Tags: spring, ibatis, spring-orm

I have the following maven dependency in my project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

We are using iBatis for ORM.

- What is the purpose of giving this dependency?
- Is this required if I to have bridge between Spring and iBatis?
- In general how Spring and iBatis linked?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/orm.html#orm-ibatis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the purpose of giving this dependency?
> Is this required if I to have bridge between Spring and iBatis?

It adds support (glue code) to integrate various ORM solutions with Spring, including Hibernate 3/4, iBatis, JDO and JPA. Of course it's not an ORM on its own, it's just a bridge. You still need to include relevant libraries.

> In general how Spring and iBatis linked?

Quoting official documentation: [*12.5. iBATIS SQL Maps*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/orm.html#orm-ibatis):

> iBATIS support works with Spring's exception hierarchy and let's you enjoy the all IoC features Spring has.
>
> Transaction management can be handled through Spring's standard facilities.